# Добавление пункта в контекстное меню SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в SQL Server 2008 появился пункт в контекстном меню - открыть таблицу?

Answer (score 1):

В SQL Server 2008 нельзя вызвать контекстное меню - он работает либо в режиме службы, либо в режиме консоли.

Если Вы имеете в виду SQL Server Management Studio - среду управления, то все зависит от того, что вы подразумеваете под "открыть таблицу". Можно посмотреть свойства - для этого есть пункт "Свойства". Можно изменить таблицу - для этого есть пункт "Изменить". Можно посмотреть содержимое - для этого есть пункт "Выбрать первые 1000 строк". Если нужно больше 1000, то в сформированном запросе просто уберите ограничение по количеству выводимых записей и выполните вручную.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.